# How can I dynamicly make form elements read-only with a directive in angular?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to give certain elements like "select, input, textarea, button" readonly when the given attribute to the directive on it has a certain name.

> All the code in this question is minified to make it more clear.

for example there is a directive '**dynamic-input-field**' on this element:

```
<ui-select ng-model="controllerData.header.subsidiary"
         theme="bootstrap"
         class="googleSearch"
         ng-disabled="quotationData.readOnly || isFieldDisabled('subsidiary')" 
         on-select="subsidiaryChanged(controllerData.header.subsidiary)"
         dynamic-input-field="A">
    <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" autofocus="true" placeholder="Subsidiary">{{$select.selected.description}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="subsidiary in presetData.subsidiariesChange | filter: {'description': $select.search}">
        <div ng-bind-html="subsidiary.description | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

With this directive I want to disable this ui-select element when it has a certain name (in this case it is **"A"**)

I have tried it with a lot of possibilities but I can't find a proper way to do this. This is my **directive**:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * @ngInject
 */
module.exports = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        compile: function (element, attrs) {
            if (attrs.dynamicInputField === "A" ) {
                // I have tried all these options but it doesn't seem to disable the select element
                // element.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
                // element.attr("ng-disabled", 'isReadOnly');
                // element.attr("ng-disabled", 'true');
                // element.attr("ng-disabled", true);
                // element.attr("ng-disabled", 'disabled');
                // element.prop('readonly', true);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that selectors can't handle the "readonly" properly. I would recommend you to use "disabled" instead, but in this case it seems you already have an directive instruction using that.